How to replace double quotes within double quotes in a string with a specific string?
name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"

i need a Python code where I need to replace double quotes with {+} except the ones in the ends, that is replace 2nd and 3rd and 4th double quote with {+}
Result required:
name = "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"

Starting and ending quotes should be left as is

You can use index and rindex to find the first and last " characters, and then replace " in between:
s = 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'
first = s.index('"')+1
last = s.rindex('"')
out = s[:first] + s[first:last].replace('"', '{+}') + s[last:]
print(out)

Output:
name = "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"


Use \ to escape the character double quote so that the double quotes inside the string will be considered as  characters
name = '\"HIGHLY\"SUCCE?SS+\"FUL\"RATE\"'


name = name[1:-1]
name = name.replace('"', '{+}')
name = f'"{name}"'
print(name)
#Output : "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"

EDIT:Only now I saw your comment in another post that you can't add \.  It is still easier then. Just prefix and suffix the name string with a single quote. (Add single quotes before and after the string and execute the following program)
name = 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'
idx = name.find('"') + 1
name = name[idx:-1]
name = name.replace('"', '{+}')
name = f'"{name}"'
print(name)

# Output : "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"

If the string is 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"', i.e if even name = is added in the string, Just add two line before and execute the same program.
name = 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'
idx = name.find('"') + 1
name = name[idx:-1]
name = name.replace('"', '{+}')
name = f'"{name}"'
print(name)

# Output : "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"


You could capture the part after the equals sign till the opening quote, and then capture the part before the last occurrence.
Then replace the double quote with {+} for the second capture group.
import re

s = 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'
pattern = r'(=\s*")(.*)"'
template = '{0}{1}"'

result = re.sub(
    pattern,
    lambda m: template.format(m[1], m[2].replace('"', "{+}")),
    s
)

print(result)

Output
name = "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"


i wont be able to add escape character, and there wont be any extra double quotes at the ends

@sreelur so then you are just replacind all double quotes?

This is actually a string:  'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'
For the above string after '=' i need to split out and replace double quotes except those @ ends with {+}

@sreelur You probably ought to edit your question in that case

There's probably some magic regular expression that will do this but there's always another way.
For example:
the_string = 'name = "HIGHLY"SUCCE?SS+"FUL"RATE"'

as_list = list(the_string)

first = the_string.find('"')
last = the_string.rfind('"')

for i, v in enumerate(as_list):
    if v == '"' and not i in {first, last}:
        as_list[i] = '{+}'

print("".join(as_list))

Output:
name = "HIGHLY{+}SUCCE?SS+{+}FUL{+}RATE"

